# How to update app?

Tags: android, string, optimization, android-studio, google-play

There seem to not be to many resources on the internet for updating an android app. So, is all that I need to do change the version number and name in the build.gradle file of my app?

```
versionCode 2
versionName "1.0.1"
```

Is that all? Now I just need to make an apk of this and upload the new apk in the developer console?

Also, the documentation states to run this on your update:

```
$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
```

How do I run that on my update?

Thanks so much for all of your help,

I hope to release my update soon!

Comment: You have to export it as signed apk. the rest procedure you have mentioned is same

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Updating the existing app is very simple. In your `build.gradle` file:

- Update the `versionCode` (Integer value greater than the previous version)
- Update the `versionName` (optional)

Then in your Android studio:

- Go to `Build` menu
- Click on `Generate Signed APK` (If you didn't set the Remember keystore password option, it will ask for existing keystore password)
- Upload the newly created APK to playstore.
- Fill the `What's new` field in the developer console
- Click on the `Publish now to Production` button (It'll automatically removes the previous version to unpublished and new build to production state)

Comment: Thats great! Thanks. So I don't need to make any new keys or signatures or anything right?

Comment: And do the users see the versionname?

Comment: They only see the version name, won't see the version code. Also you don't need to new keys. You should use only one key to update your app. If you create a new key the app will be treated as a new one

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: You can read more about keys in detail here : http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Wait one more question

Comment: How do I do this: `$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk`

Comment: The documentation says to run that on my update to see if the key is the same. I have no idea how to run that on my application

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: When you choose `Generate Signed APK`. The android studio behind the scene does it for you. It'll sign the apk and give it to you. If you manually want to sign the apk, in that case only you need to execute that command by yourself.

Comment: Oh, thanks for clearing that up for me. If I wanted to do it manually, which I don't, but if I did (for curiosity) How would I?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: You can see the full step-by-step explanation of manually signing in the link I provided above. Check the `Manually sign your app` section :)

Comment: @downvoter: Can you explain the reason for down vote ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, creating an android update for your apk is fairly simple. Go into your build.gradle file and update the following

1. version code (always an int, has to be higher than any previous versions Always)
2. version name (any string like v 1.1 or ver 1.2 Butterfly)

Once your done generate a signed apk of your app. I recommend using the direct Generate Signed Apk option in android using your keystore and your done.

Comment: You only have to increase the version code. version name can stay the same.

Comment: I dont have to make any new keys or signitures or anything right? Just a new APK?

Comment: And do I get rid of my current APK? What would the process be in the dev. console?